# DHCP Help 3560-CX + Aruba AP515

Tags: cisco, vlan, switching, dhcp, aruba

## The problem

VLAN 100 is not assigning IP address to the SSID Guest from the AP, but Aruba is Tagging the SSID to be VLAN 100. How do I get the Switch to assign the DHCP? On the switch, it seems to have dhcp correctly setup, but it is never assigning anything to the Wireless AP that is correctly tagging it to vlan 100.

## What is interesting

When I am on the mgmt ssid it is able to see the switch and the other 2 switches, but the GUEST SSID as i would think has no access (even if i setup a static IP) to anything as intended but unable to get DHCP.

On My Wireless AP I have the following configuration:

```
version 8.4.0.0-8.4.0
virtual-controller-country US
name Home-VC
virtual-controller-ip 10.10.10.11
terminal-access
ntp-server time.google.com
clock timezone Central-Time -06 00
clock summer-time CDT recurring second sunday march 02:00 first sunday november 02:00
rf-band 5.0
allow-new-aps
allowed-ap d0:15:a6:cb:0a:04
allowed-ap d0:15:a6:ca:f2:98
arm
wide-bands 5ghz
80mhz-support
min-tx-power 9
max-tx-power 127
band-steering-mode prefer-5ghz
air-time-fairness-mode preferred-access
channel-quality-aware-arm-disable
client-aware
scanning
client-match slb-mode 3
rf dot11g-radio-profile
max-distance 0
max-tx-power 9
min-tx-power 6
disable-arm-wids-functions off
free-channel-index 40
rf dot11a-radio-profile
max-distance 0
max-tx-power 18
min-tx-power 12
disable-arm-wids-functions off
syslog-level warn ap-debug
syslog-level warn network
syslog-level warn security
syslog-level warn system
syslog-level warn user
syslog-level warn user-debug
syslog-level warn wireless
extended-ssid
wlan access-rule Data
index 0
rule any any match any any any permit
wlan access-rule default_wired_port_profile
index 1
rule any any match any any any permit
wlan access-rule wired-SetMeUp
index 2
rule masterip 0.0.0.0 match tcp 80 80 permit
rule masterip 0.0.0.0 match tcp 4343 4343 permit
rule any any match udp 67 68 permit
rule any any match udp 53 53 permit
wlan access-rule 1008-mgmt
index 3
vlan 1
rule any any match any any any permit
rule masterip 0.0.0.0 match tcp 80 80 permit
rule masterip 0.0.0.0 match tcp 4343 4343 permit
rule any any match udp 67 68 permit
rule any any match udp 53 53 permit
wlan access-rule Guest
index 4
vlan 100
rule any any match any any any permit
rule any any match udp 67 68 permit
rule any any match udp 53 53 permit
rule any any match webcategory spam-urls deny
rule any any match webcategory malware-sites deny
rule any any match webcategory adult-and-pornography deny
rule any any match webcategory dating deny
rule any any match webcategory keyloggers-and-monitoring deny
rule any any match webcategory gross deny
rule any any match webcategory cheating deny
rule any any match webcategory phishing-and-other-frauds deny
rule any any match webcategory proxy-avoidance-and-anonymizers deny
rule any any match webcategory spyware-and-adware deny
rule any any match webcategory nudity deny
rule any any match webcategory bot-nets deny
rule any any match webcategory hate-and-racism deny
rule any any match webcategory violence deny
rule any any match webcategory gambling deny
wlan access-rule Any
index 5
rule any any match any any any permit
wlan ssid-profile Data
enable
index 0
type employee
essid Data
opmode wpa3-sae-aes
max-authentication-failures 0
vlan 90
rf-band all
captive-portal disable
dtim-period 1
broadcast-filter arp
dmo-channel-utilization-threshold 90
local-probe-req-thresh 0
max-clients-threshold 64
dot11v
wlan ssid-profile 1008-mgmt
enable
index 1
type employee
essid 1008-mgmt
opmode wpa3-sae-aes
max-authentication-failures 0
vlan 1
rf-band all
captive-portal disable
dtim-period 1
broadcast-filter arp
dmo-channel-utilization-threshold 90
local-probe-req-thresh 0
max-clients-threshold 64
dot11v
wlan ssid-profile Guest
enable
index 2
type employee
essid Guest
opmode opensystem
max-authentication-failures 0
vlan 100
rf-band all
captive-portal disable
dtim-period 1
broadcast-filter none
content-filtering
dmo-channel-utilization-threshold 90
local-probe-req-thresh 0
max-clients-threshold 64
auth-survivability cache-time-out 24
dpi
url-visibility
wlan captive-portal
background-color 16777215
banner-color 16750848
banner-text "Welcome to Guest Network"
terms-of-use "This network is not secure, and use is at your own risk"
use-policy "Please read terms and conditions before using Guest Network"
wlan external-captive-portal
server localhost
port 80
url "/"
auth-text "Authenticated"
auto-whitelist-disable
https
blacklist-time 3600
auth-failure-blacklist-time 3600
ids
wireless-containment none
infrastructure-detection-level high
client-detection-level high
infrastructure-protection-level low
client-protection-level low
ip dhcp Guest
server-type Centralized,L2
disable-split-tunnel
server-vlan 100
wired-port-profile wired-SetMeUp
switchport-mode access
allowed-vlan all
native-vlan guest
no shutdown
access-rule-name wired-SetMeUp
speed auto
duplex auto
no poe
type guest
captive-portal disable
no dot1x
wired-port-profile default_wired_port_profile
switchport-mode trunk
allowed-vlan all
native-vlan 1
no shutdown
access-rule-name default_wired_port_profile
speed auto
duplex full
no poe
type employee
auth-server InternalServer
captive-portal disable
no dot1x
enet0-port-profile default_wired_port_profile
uplink
preemption
enforce none
failover-internet-pkt-lost-cnt 10
failover-internet-pkt-send-freq 30
failover-vpn-timeout 180
airgroup
disable
airgroupservice airplay
disable
description AirPlay
airgroupservice airprint
disable
description AirPrint
cluster-security
allow-low-assurance-devices
```

On my Switch I have the following Configuration:

```
Building configuration...
Current configuration : 4310 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 02:16:14 UTC Wed Apr 7 2021 by admin
! NVRAM config last updated at 02:06:33 UTC Wed Apr 7 2021 by admin
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
service dhcp
!
hostname Switch
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no aaa new-model
switch 1 provision ws-c3560cx-12pd-s
system mtu routing 1500
!
!
!
!
ip routing
no ip dhcp relay information check
!
ip dhcp pool guest-0100
network 10.10.100.0 255.255.255.0
lease 0 0 1
!
ip dhcp pool mgmt-010
network 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.224
default-router 10.10.10.1
lease 0 0 1
!
!
ip igmp snooping vlan 10 last-member-query-count 2
ip igmp snooping vlan 10 last-member-query-interval 1000
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-2991811840
enrollment selfsigned
subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-2991811840
revocation-check none
rsakeypair TP-self-signed-2991811840
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
lacp system-priority 1000
!
!
!
!
!
vlan configuration 100
no ip igmp snooping
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
vlan group Guest vlan-list 100
vlan group mgmt-0010 vlan-list 10
!
lldp run
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
lacp port-priority 1000
channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
flowcontrol receive desired
spanning-tree portfast edge
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
flowcontrol receive desired
spanning-tree portfast edge
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
switchport port-security violation shutdown vlan
flowcontrol receive desired
spanning-tree portfast network
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
switchport mode trunk
ip dhcp relay information trusted
spanning-tree portfast edge
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2
!
interface Vlan1
ip address 10.10.10.4 255.255.255.224
!
interface Vlan10
description mgmt
ip address pool mgmt-010
!
interface Vlan100
description Guest
ip dhcp relay information trusted
ip address pool guest-0100
!
ip default-gateway 10.10.10.1
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip http server
ip http banner
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http path flash:CCP-CATALYST
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
login
transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
login
transport input ssh
end
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an IP address to the VLAN 100 SVI to be the gateway address. DHCP will automatically assign DHCP on an addressed interface from the correct pool based on the interface address. You also need to have the gateway address in the pool. You probably want to define a DNS server in the DHCP pool, too.

```
ip dhcp pool guest-0100
 network 10.10.100.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.10.100.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8            ! Example of using the Google DNS server
 lease 0 0 1
!
interface Vlan100
 description Guest
 ip address 10.10.100.1
!
```

Also, never use the `ip default-gateway` command on a device with routing enabled. You create a default route:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <next hop address>
```

Cisco has a document that explains the differences: *[Configuring a Gateway of Last Resort Using IP Commands](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/16448-default.html)*
:

> The **[ip default-gateway](https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3/ipaddr/command/reference/ip1_i1g.html#wp1080489)** command differs from the other two
> commands. It should only be used when **ip routing** is disabled on
> the Cisco router.

Comment: `ip default-gateway` only applies in "host mode". Once routing is enabled, the command has no effect, but will still be in the configuration.

Comment: I updated my 3560CX switch removed , default-gateway and routing .. updated as you mentioned and i am still unable to get a DHCP on the Guest SSID. Did you mean to leave out the netmask in the interface?

Comment: No I did not mean to leave it out. If you removed the routing, the you should put the DHCP on the router interface for that network.

Comment: Thanks for that ... BTW, The wireless APs are on interfaces 11 and 12

Comment: @RonMaupin Still not working is their something i am doing wrong on the AP or the interface?