# Losing connection when connecting a server to Stratix 5400?

Tags: ethernet, spanning-tree, lan

I have a problem that when connecting a server to Stratix 5400 the Stratix loses connection for some seconds which causes a Safety Fault for the line because we have Safety PLC’s any help.

```
,Software verison is 15.2 (non crypto)
,STP setting: MSTP
,VTP mode:Transparent
,Vlan Management: Default and all of the used posrts are in
,Port type: I tried both Trunk and Dynamic auto but same issue
```

on my switch I have this configuration

```
!
! Last configuration change at 06:19:25 UTC Tue Apr 13 2021 by admin 
! NVRAM config last updated at 06:19:25 UTC Tue Apr 13 2021 by admin 
! 
version 15.2 
service nagle 
no service pad 
service tcp-keepalives-in 
service tcp-keepalives-out 
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone 
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone 
service password-encryption 
service unsupported-transceiver 
no service dhcp 
! 
hostname L04_BLISS 
! 
boot-start-marker 
boot-end-marker 
! 
! 
logging buffered 16384 
no logging console 
enable secret level 1 5 $1$lyxC$gX/xJyzgZZbvAto5ghwZw/ 
enable secret 5 $1$49To$3.3hDvkcE7/S6NcFp7IU.. 
! 
username admin privilege 15 secret 5 $1$g.1c$hMMHErqIqYrad3FxxZuDh/ 
no aaa new-model 
system mtu routing 1500 
no ip source-route 
! 
! 
! 
no ip domain-lookup 
ip igmp snooping querier 
vtp mode transparent 
! 
! 
! 
! 
! 
udld aggressive 
 
ptp mode forward  
! 
! 
spanning-tree mode mst 
spanning-tree extend system-id 
cip security password 143206030916242E30 
errdisable recovery cause udld 
errdisable recovery cause bpduguard 
errdisable recovery cause security-violation 
errdisable recovery cause channel-misconfig 
errdisable recovery cause pagp-flap 
errdisable recovery cause link-flap 
errdisable recovery cause sfp-config-mismatch 
errdisable recovery cause gbic-invalid 
errdisable recovery cause l2ptguard 
errdisable recovery cause psecure-violation 
errdisable recovery cause port-mode-failure 
errdisable recovery cause dhcp-rate-limit 
errdisable recovery cause pppoe-ia-rate-limit 
errdisable recovery cause mac-limit 
errdisable recovery cause vmps 
errdisable recovery cause storm-control 
errdisable recovery cause inline-power 
errdisable recovery cause arp-inspection 
errdisable recovery cause link-monitor-failure 
errdisable recovery cause oam-remote-failure 
errdisable recovery cause loopback 
errdisable recovery cause small-frame 
errdisable recovery cause psp 
errdisable recovery interval 30 
! 
alarm profile defaultPort 
 alarm not-operating  
 syslog not-operating  
 notifies not-operating  
! 
alarm profile ab-alarm 
 alarm link-fault not-forwarding not-operating fcs-error  
 syslog link-fault not-forwarding not-operating fcs-error  
 notifies link-fault not-forwarding not-operating fcs-error  
 relay-major not-forwarding  
! 
alarm facility power-supply rps disable 
alarm facility power-supply rps notifies 
alarm facility power-supply rps relay major 
alarm facility temperature secondary notifies 
alarm facility temperature secondary syslog 
alarm facility temperature secondary high 90 
alarm facility temperature secondary low 0 
! 
! 
vlan internal allocation policy ascending 
! 
vlan 999 
 name VLAN0999  
! 
vlan 1000  
! 
! 
class-map match-all 1588-PTP-General 
 match access-group 107 
class-map match-all 1588-PTP-Event 
 match access-group 106 
class-map match-all qos-group-2 
 match qos-group 2 
class-map match-all qos-group-0 
 match qos-group 0 
class-map match-all qos-group-1 
 match qos-group 1 
class-map match-all CIP-Implicit_dscp_any 
 match access-group 104 
class-map match-all CIP-Other 
 match access-group 105 
class-map match-all voip-data 
 match ip dscp ef  
class-map match-any voip-control 
 match ip dscp cs3  af31  
class-map match-all CIP-Implicit_dscp_43 
 match access-group 103 
class-map match-all CIP-Implicit_dscp_55 
 match access-group 101 
class-map match-all CIP-Implicit_dscp_47 
 match access-group 102 
! 
policy-map Policymap-Output-Wireless 
 class qos-group-0 
  priority 
  police 4000000 
 class qos-group-1 
  bandwidth percent 40  
 class qos-group-2 
  bandwidth percent 40  
 class class-default 
  bandwidth percent 16  
policy-map Voice-Map 
 class voip-data 
  police 320000 8000 conform-action set-qos-transmit 1 exceed-action set-qos-transmit 3 
 class voip-control 
  police 32000 8000 conform-action set-qos-transmit 2 exceed-action set-qos-transmit 3 
policy-map Output-accesspoint 
 class qos-group-0 
  priority 
  police 4000000 
 class qos-group-1 
  bandwidth percent 19  
 class qos-group-2 
  bandwidth percent 40  
 class class-default 
  bandwidth percent 40  
policy-map Policymap-Output-Default 
 class qos-group-0 
  priority 
  police 4000000 
 class qos-group-1 
  bandwidth percent 25  
 class qos-group-2 
  bandwidth percent 25  
 class class-default 
  bandwidth percent 25  
policy-map PTP-Event-Priority 
 class qos-group-0 
  priority 
 class qos-group-1 
  bandwidth remaining percent 40  
 class qos-group-2 
  bandwidth remaining percent 40  
 class class-default 
  bandwidth remaining percent 20  
policy-map CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 class CIP-Implicit_dscp_55 
  set qos-group 1 
 class CIP-Implicit_dscp_47 
  set qos-group 1 
 class CIP-Implicit_dscp_43 
  set qos-group 1 
 class CIP-Implicit_dscp_any 
  set qos-group 2 
 class CIP-Other 
  set qos-group 2 
 class 1588-PTP-Event 
  set qos-group 0 
 class 1588-PTP-General 
  set qos-group 1 
policy-map Policymap-Output-Phone 
 class qos-group-0 
  priority 
  police 4000000 
 class qos-group-1 
  bandwidth percent 60  
 class qos-group-2 
  bandwidth percent 20  
 class class-default 
  bandwidth percent 10  
! 
! 
! 
! 
! 
! 
macro global description ab-global | ab-password 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/1 
 description BLISS 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/2 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/3 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/4 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/5 
 description PLC_PNL 
 switchport mode trunk 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/6 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/7 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/8 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/9 
 description Geo_A 
 switchport mode trunk 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/10 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/11 
 description Geo_B 
 switchport mode trunk 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/12 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/13 
 description Geo_C 
 switchport mode trunk 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/14 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/15 
 description Geo_D 
 switchport mode trunk 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/16 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/17 
 description Geo_E 
 switchport mode trunk 
 macro description switch-automation 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/18 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/19 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface GigabitEthernet1/20 
 alarm profile ab-alarm 
 service-policy input CIP-PTP-Traffic 
 service-policy output Policymap-Output-Default 
! 
interface Vlan1 
 ip address 192.168.0.5 255.255.0.0 
 cip enable 
! 
interface Vlan999 
 no ip address 
! 
ip forward-protocol nd 
! 
ip http server 
ip http authentication local 
ip http session-idle-timeout 1200  
! 
! 
access-list 101 permit udp any eq 2222 any dscp 55 
access-list 102 permit udp any eq 2222 any dscp 47 
access-list 103 permit udp any eq 2222 any dscp 43 
access-list 104 permit udp any eq 2222 any 
access-list 105 permit udp any eq 44818 any 
access-list 105 permit tcp any eq 44818 any 
access-list 106 permit udp any eq 319 any 
access-list 107 permit udp any eq 320 any 
! 
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart 
snmp-server enable traps transceiver all 
snmp-server enable traps call-home message-send-fail server-fail 
snmp-server enable traps tty 
snmp-server enable traps eigrp 
snmp-server enable traps ospf state-change 
snmp-server enable traps ospf errors 
snmp-server enable traps ospf retransmit 
snmp-server enable traps ospf lsa 
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change nssa-trans-change 
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change shamlink interface 
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change shamlink neighbor 
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific errors 
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific retransmit 
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific lsa 
snmp-server enable traps license 
snmp-server enable traps ethernet cfm cc mep-up mep-down cross-connect loop config 
snmp-server enable traps ethernet cfm crosscheck mep-missing mep-unknown service-up 
snmp-server enable traps auth-framework sec-violation 
snmp-server enable traps bgp cbgp2 
snmp-server enable traps ether-oam 
snmp-server enable traps cef resource-failure peer-state-change peer-fib-state-change inconsistency 
snmp-server enable traps cluster 
snmp-server enable traps config-copy 
snmp-server enable traps config 
snmp-server enable traps config-ctid 
snmp-server enable traps trustsec-sxp conn-srcaddr-err msg-parse-err conn-config-err binding-err conn-up conn-down binding-expn-fail oper-nodeid-change binding-conflict 
snmp-server enable traps energywise 
snmp-server enable traps fru-ctrl 
snmp-server enable traps entity 
snmp-server enable traps event-manager 
snmp-server enable traps hsrp 
snmp-server enable traps ipmulticast 
snmp-server enable traps isis 
snmp-server enable traps msdp 
snmp-server enable traps ospfv3 state-change 
snmp-server enable traps ospfv3 errors 
snmp-server enable traps power-ethernet police 
snmp-server enable traps pim neighbor-change rp-mapping-change invalid-pim-message 
snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold 
snmp-server enable traps rep 
snmp-server enable traps ipsla 
snmp-server enable traps bridge newroot topologychange 
snmp-server enable traps stpx inconsistency root-inconsistency loop-inconsistency 
snmp-server enable traps syslog 
snmp-server enable traps vtp 
snmp-server enable traps vlancreate 
snmp-server enable traps vlandelete 
snmp-server enable traps flash insertion removal 
snmp-server enable traps port-security 
snmp-server enable traps envmon fan shutdown supply temperature status 
snmp-server enable traps stackwise 
snmp-server enable traps ethernet cfm alarm 
snmp-server enable traps alarms informational 
snmp-server enable traps bulkstat collection transfer 
snmp-server enable traps vrfmib vrf-up vrf-down vnet-trunk-up vnet-trunk-down 
snmp-server enable traps errdisable 
snmp-server enable traps mac-notification change move threshold 
snmp-server enable traps vlan-membership 
! 
! 
line con 0 
 login local 
line vty 0 4 
 login local 
 transport input none 
line vty 5 15 
 login local 
 transport input none 
! 
! 
end
```

Comment: Probably a reconvergence of STP, but you have not included the switch configuration, so all we can do is guess, which is off-topic here. Please edit the question to include the switch configuration.

Comment: Actually, I mean the configuration in the switch, much like [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/73462/8499).

Comment: I don’t know if I can do this in startix to export a configuration, however if you need a specific question please ask it.

Comment: You should be able to download *config.text* via web GUI.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration looks very much like a Cisco IOS configuration. You could try using the global `spanning-tree portfast default` global command. It only affects access interfaces, not trunk interfaces. Or, you could try the `#spanning-tree portfast` interface command for a specific access interface.

Portfast bypasses the STP blocking, listening, and learning cycle and goes straight into forwarding, so you should not use it on links that will have traffic for things like switches.

Answer (score 0):

> server to Stratix loses connection for some seconds

(assuming *layer-2* connectivity is lost)

MSTP is active but hasn't been configured sufficiently.

Likely, your problem is a combination of the missing *root-guard*, *tcn-guard* and *portfast* options.

You should at least

- select a (central) switch as root bridge by settings its priority to 0 or 1 (or 0 / 4096 when displayed in multiples of 4096)
- select another switch as backup root bridge by settings its priority to 2 or 3 (or 8192 / 12288 for multiples of 4096)
- set up end-node ports with the *Port Fast* option - without it, any port is blocked for a few seconds on link-up or topology change
- optionally protect end-user ports with the *bdpu-guard* option - disables port when BPDUs from an unauthorized switch are received
- protect all ports that never lead towards the root bridge with the *root-guard* option
- protect all ports not connected to other switches with the *tcn-guard* option
- protect all external ports (esp. WAN) with the *bpdu-filter* option